# android sdk detecting emulator mode in java

Tags: android

Is there something I can code to skip the license check when running on the emulator?    i don't want to comment out as I may forget to re-enable the check when releasing to the play store.  i already have a check for "isDeviceOnline()" but this call receives TRUE.

(for some reason I always get a network error in my licensing check code when running on the emulator)

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is emulator is not connected to network, causing network error. May be should restart emulator and make sure you have network connection.

I generally use Genymotion's emulator and they are pretty reliable and fast.